# Parameterize Helm values yaml file in a CI pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have two projects:

> Project A - Contains the Source code for my Microservice application
>
> Project B - Contains the Kubernetes resources for Project A using Helm

Both the Projects reside in their own separate git repositories.

Project A builds using a full blown CI pipeline that build a Docker image with a tag version and pushes it into the Docker hub and then writes the version number for the Docker image into Project B via a git push from the CI server. It does so by committing a simple txt file with the Docker version that it just built.

So far so good! I now have Project B which contains this Docker version for the Microservice Project A and I now want to pass / inject this value into the Values.yaml so that when I package the Project B via Helm, I have the latest version.

Any ideas how I could get this implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> via a git push from the CI server. It does so by committing a simple txt file with the Docker version that it just built.

What I usually do here, is that I write the value to the correct field in the yaml directly. To work with yaml on the command line, I recommend the cli tool [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

I usually use full Kubernetes `Deployment` manifest yaml and I typically update the image field with this `yq` command:

```
yq write --inplace deployment.yaml 'spec.template.spec.containers(name==myapp).image' <my-registry>/<my-image-repo>/<image-name>:<tag-name>
```

and after that commit the yaml file to the repo with yaml manifests.

Now, you use Helm but it is still Yaml, so you should be able to solve this in a similar way. Maybe something like:

```
yq write --inplace values.yaml 'app.image' <my-image>
```